# What does the light of day mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> The men of Kent may well have been mainly Jutish, and the other major
> peoples certainly thought themselves either 'Angles' or 'Saxons'. But
> archaeology does not suggest a very firm distinction, and by the late
> sixth century, when the kingdoms emerge into ***the light of day***, there
> is much blurring at the edges.

What does "the light of day" mean? Is it similar to ***at that point*** or ***in the moment***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***To emerge into the light of day*** is a variant of the idiomatic phrase ***to see the light of day***:

> If something sees the light of day at a particular time, it comes into
> existence or is made known to the public at that time.
>
> - This
>   extraordinary document first saw the light of day in 1966. ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-see-the-light-of-day#:%7E:text=phrase%20%5BVERB%20inflects%5D,light%20of%20day%20in%201966.))

Note that ***to emerge into the light of day*** is slightly redundant, which could be voluntary (for the purpose of emphasis), because ***to emerge*** already has the meaning of

> to begin to exist or have power or influence ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/emerge))

or

> show signs of life ([WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/emerge.html#C0-2))

Here is an example where this expression is used with the meaning ***to be made known to the public at that time***:

> The damage ***emerged into the light of day*** to Theresa May’s political discomfort in the 2017 election. ([the Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2019/sep/04/sajid-javid-reversing-austerity-cuts))

Note that this phrase can be used literally, meaning "to show oneself in the light of the day/ to appear":

> Finally, Rukmini ***emerged into the light of day***, holding Durga in her arms. ([source](https://www.gatesfoundation.org/Media-Center/Speeches/2010/06/Women-Deliver-Conference))